# How to disable the "local declaration of 'foo' hides instance variable" warning?

Tags: xcode, llvm

I understand what the warning says. This is exactly how scoping rules work. I appreciate that some people want a nanny. I don't. How can I disable this warning?

Comment: The warnings in Xcode are rarely a case of nannying - ignore them at your own peril. You can disable this warning by naming your local variable something else.

Comment: You like this warning. I don't. I am asking how to disable it, not how to change my coding style. Scoping rules exist to make is possible to use the same name in different contexts to refer to different things. What you are suggesting essentially makes one global namespace. If you like this style, I encourage you to employ it. I am looking for a way to employ a different style without the compiler nagging me.

Comment: Just go into the warnings section of the build settings in Xcode and disable the warning.

Comment: Thank yout. What is the actual setting that disables this?

Comment: I would hate to maintain your code.... "Oh look! The variable foo is used for 15 different things in this function!!"

Comment: @CJohnson Perhaps you meant to say "in this class," which is a legitimate concern. But I prefer any limited ambiguity that creates to the alternative, which is "Oh look! Some of my variables have arbitrary prefixes that make their names more difficult to remember and apply consistently."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The warning name you're looking for is "shadow-ivar". It appears in the log in Xcode 4.3 as something like `warning: local declaration of 'foo' hides instance variable [-Wshadow-ivar]`.

I still don't see it in the project's Build Settings list, but `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow-ivar"` will take care of it in one file at a time. I actually like to turn it off for particular functions and then turn it on again. That way it ceases to nag me where I've decided I don't care but will warn me again in new code.

Comment: To turn on and off for only one particular function, see my answer, if you still want to :)

Comment: Hi @jab, would you know if there's a canonical list somewhere with all the `clang diagnostic ignored` options? [The manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages) does not contain this one, for example.

Comment: I've never found a list. I don't mind too much - I typically only want to disable *some* warnings *after* I've been warned and thoughtfully decided to ignore it.

Answer (score 6):

You can't disable this warning in the current version of XCode. There is no build setting for it, nor does it have a warning ID which you could use to pass a flag to the compiler to tell it to quit whining.

For future reference, you can find that warning ID by going to the Log Navigator, clicking on the most recent build where the warning appeared, drilling down into the log to find the point where the 'compile' task shows up with an exclamation mark and click the 'more detail' button, which looks like a gray callout with 5 horizontal lines. You'll see the warnings/errors listed in detail, and if there was a warning ID it would appear on the line detailing the warning in yellow. At least, thats what I've been told by one of the Compiler Engineers at Apple. I have yet to see a warning that I actually want to disable have an ID appear in the log.

File a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple, tell them you want more options to disable warnings in XCode and list this one specifically.

Comment: I wish it was easier to suppress warnings in XCode - I actually asked several Apple engineers at WWDC how to handle it, and their responses were all 'file a bug report'. It's unfortunate that XCode isn't more customizable, but at least I learned that Apple actually uses bug reports to drive new features.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode 4.4 this can be disabled by going to the build setting "Other Warning Flags" and setting the value "-Wno-shadow-ivar"

Comment: When I added this to the project's build settings in Xcode 4.4.1, I still got the warnings. I also tried adding it to the target's build settings, but then the compiler failed with the error "cc1obj: error: unrecognized command line option '-Wno-shadow-ivar.'"

Comment: I'm at 4.5.2 by now, but this worked fine for me (finally got rid of those irritating warnings -- you can see you're shadowing the instance variable because it has a different color than instance variables!). Go to Targets, Build Settings, find "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1 - Warnings - All languages", under that click open Other Warning flags, and add "-Wno-shadow-ivar" to both Debug and Release. Then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes, that did it for me. Thanks for the extra detail, Danny.

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString *foo;

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wshadow-ivar"

- (void)myFunctionWithShadow_ivarWarningsIgnored {

    NSString *foo = @"...";
    NSLog(@"This shouldn't get a warning %@", foo);

}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

- (void)myFunctionWithShadow_ivarWarningsNotIgnored {

    NSString *foo = @"...";
    NSLog(@"and this should %@", foo);

}
```

Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

Update for Xcode 8.3 - Bug in compiler yields "Declaration shadows a local variable" in some instances when it intentional... and the nanny panics.

For example in Objective C:

Given

```
typedef BOOL ( ^BoolBoolBlock ) ( BOOL );
```

And the nature of Apple Blocks will make any variable declared in the immediate outer scope to a Block, a global to the block (pseudo globals). This results in the warnings (and errors if warnings == errors in your settings) on the line `BOOL theResult = false;`:

```
- (BoolBoolBlock) boolBoolBlock {
    BoolBoolBlock    theResult = nil;

    theResult = ^BOOL ( unused BOOL is ) {
        BOOL    theResult = false; // hides (shadows) the outer theResult (a good thing)

        /*
         call back code goes here,
         all variables local in scope to this method are global to the block so be careful
         */
        return theResult;
    };

    return theResult;
}
```

The nanny sees `BoolBoolBlock    theResult = nil;` getting shadow-blocked by `BOOL    theResult = false;` which is actually intentional for two reasons in this case:

1. by convention in my code ALL return values are theResult no matter what
2. is a positive side effects because I am morally opposed to globals.

In other words this entire construct is setup to block the pseudo global mechanisms of Apple Blocks and put structure on that chaos. Blocking the method's "theResult" from use in the block that the method returns is a *good thing* ... yet the nanny has a hissy fit.

To calm the nanny down (get rid of warnings or possibly errors if you have the discipline to set warnings as errors), you simply make this setting change in your Project File -> Build Settings -> filter on "Other" -> Hidden Local Variables -> change to "No" ... or visually:

[image: screen shot of Xcode Build Settings showing Hidden Local Variables set to "No"]